# Running multiple DNS requests in parallel

Tags: c++, macos, networking, dns

I'd like to resolve numerous URLs in the shortest time possible on the MacOS platform. Basically, my input is a long list of URLs, and the output should be a long list of IP addresses matching those URLs (if multiple IPs relate to single URL, I just pick the first one for simplicity).

My first attempt was to allocate a separate thread for each DNS request, that mostly waits on a socket until the response is available (I'm using the blocking function `getaddrinfo()`, so most of the time the thread are idle).

I wonder if there are more efficient approaches for dealing with this problem, in terms of memory/CPU resources (like cooperative context switch)?

According to one of the advices I got in the comments, perhaps there's an option to run all of those DNS requests in parallel using one thread - since most of the time the thread will wait on DNS response, it can simply send each dns, which is a relatively fast action, then move to the next task without waiting for the response which we expect to start from a triggered event.

Comment: Did it work? I wouldn't necessarily use 2500 threads but instead a thread pool, and hand them work via some sort of queue, but your method seems sound.

Comment: Use `getaddrinfo_a`

Comment: I've added the operating system (macOS) unfortunately `getaddrinfo_a` is only for linux

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do something like this. But, like everything else in C++, it's not a magic button, somewhere, that needs to just be located and pushed. All the work must be done, hands on. Prepare to invest a few years in writing your own RFC 1035 resolver that sends multiple DNS queries, and waits for them to come back, doing all the book-keeping. I did this fun little project some years ago, for Courier, to be able to optimize simultaneous DNS lookups for TXT and A records for DNSBL lookups at the same time (some else did the heavy lifting, I cleaned up).

Comment: [c-ares?](https://c-ares.org/)

Comment: No don't use threads for this. You can resolves thousands of requests with a single thread (because most of them will be blocked on IO waiting). At the lowest level you need to understand `select()` ,`pselect()`, `poll()`, `epoll()` etc but there are libraries out there to help such as `libevent`. Though `getaddrinfo()` is reentrant does not mean that it is implemented efficiently for multiple parallel requests you may want to look at direct access to the DNS layer.

Comment: A simple speedup would be taking all your URL and finding common domain. That way you can resolve thousands of URLs by simply retrieving the IP of one domain.

Comment: This advice may be dated (Its a long time since I did this). But you can compile libCurl with [c-Ares](https://c-ares.org/) to get parallel DNS resolution at the Curl library level.

Comment: Help speed up the processes by running your own recursive DNS server locally. Correct configuration can get them to pull subdomain information in parallel even before you request it.